# WP8.1 AppBar size change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How do I monitor AppBar's size changes? Specifically, I want to know when it gets opened(to show secondary commands and labels underneath icons).
There is a SizeChanged event, but it fires only before AppBar is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

[CommandBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279427) has [Opened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.opened) and [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closed) events. They are fired when *SecondayCommands* are shown/hidden.

Note that those events will be fired **only** if you have *SecondayCommands* in your AppBar.

As I've checked - Opening/Closing your AppBar doesn't change its ActualHeight. If you want to see its size changing you can play with [ClosedDisplayMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closeddisplaymode.aspx) - for example put this code in your `AppBarButton.Click`:

```
private void AppBarToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(BottomAppBar.ActualHeight.ToString());
    if (BottomAppBar.ClosedDisplayMode == AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact)
       BottomAppBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal;
    else BottomAppBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
}
```

The code above changes *ActualHeight* and thus *SizeChanged* event is being fired.

Comment: Thank you. I missed it because I didn't have SecondaryCommands set.
But I still can't read AppBar's new size. Both AppBar.ActualHeight and CommandBar.ActualHeight remain unchanged.

Comment: @eggplant I've put some more information into my answer.